# How do I pass a unique property value on my POST request using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
const postResponse = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}register`, {
    name: `Nadia`,
    email: 'nadia@noemail.com'
}
```

Hello! So my post request has specific set of payloads required however its validating when the name used is already existing. I wanted to know how I can give the property name a unique value every time I run it. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know how I can give the property name a unique value every
>   time I run it.

Try append the *date millisecond* value to it

```
const postResponse = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}register`, {
    name: `Nadia` + (new Date().getTime()),
    email: 'nadia@noemail.com'
}
```

**Edit**

If there are multiple clients, then also append the client-id or name to it

```
var clientId = "client1";
const postResponse = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}register`, {
    name: `Nadia` + (new Date().getTime()) + "_" + clientId,
    email: 'nadia@noemail.com'
}
```

Comment: Two clients may pass the same time value.

Comment: adding the data and time helped! thank you gurvinder372!

Answer (score 0):

Clients cannot synchronize between them.
This kind of check has to be performed since a centralized node : the server.
And from the server side, the best one candidate to do it is a database.

At each request processing, in the NodeJS side, check in the DB, whether a User resource contains this name. 
Then process the request according to.